# How to set table row at specific value when table height is 100%?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

i would like to make a list of files in a table that takes 100% in height :)

Here's my HTML (it's jade (pug), because i use NodeJS) :

```
div.table-responsive
  table
    tr(style='line-height: 2vh;height: 2vh;')
      th File
      th Type
      th Size
      th Options
    tr(style='line-height: 2vh;height: 2vh;')
      td Jill
      td Smith
      td 50
      td test
    tr(style='line-height: 2vh;height: 2vh;')
      td Eve
      td Jackson
      td 94
      td test
```

Here's also my CSS :

```
table {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: whitesmoke;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 4%;
}
```

And here's the render : 
[image]

So how can i put all row at 2vh height (for example) and leave a blank in table when the is no rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an fix by using the responsive class as background

```
table {
    color: black;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td, th {
    padding: 1%;
}

.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 4%;
    background: whitesmoke;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

and removing this : `(style='line-height: 2vh;height: 2vh;')`

Now the result looks like this :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j3fV.png)

(i'm not able to post inline image)
Thanks!